# Condense paragraph into one line in LaTeX

Tags: macros, texstudio

I want to figure out how to condense LaTeX script into one line. I have a sample LaTeX script which looks like this:

[image: My Sample Document]

My first paragraph is broken into many lines, and I find it time consuming to remove all the "spaces" between them to condense it into one line eg the highlighted text in the image.

I know LaTeX doesn't read new lines however, I run my LaTeX file into a program that interprets these as new lines which I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a quick workaround that I can use to convert first paragraph to look like my second paragraph?

Ideally, I need this to be done in TexStudio where I highlight the paragraph I want and condense it into one line. At the moment, I know there is "hard line break" and setting it to 0 works. But I need a quick work around.

Any guide/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your platform has GNU-like scripting and core utilities, you could probably process the file via command line. the `tr` utility is useful. You can easily search online for how to replace newline with space, using `tr`. So, that would occur outside of TeX.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'tr'. Ideally I want to do it within TexStudio or if I can select the paragraph I want to condense and hit a short cut key.

Comment: Alan, I recommend that you edit the original question, and include your above comment. That will help others focus on what you really need.

Comment: I'd use TexStudio's multicursor for this task: Click left mouse button (LMB) at the beginning of line 5. Do **NOT** release LMB. Press CTRL+ALT. Do not release. Move your mouse down to line 11. Release LMB, CTRL, ALT. Press and release BACKSPACE and SPACE.

Comment: any editor should be able to do this, it is `fill-paragraph` in emacs (M-q key) or simply do a regular expression replace in that region of white space to a single space

Comment: Most editors (I'm not sure about TexStudio) offer search-and-replace in a selection only. So: select the first paragraph, click Replace or CTRL-H, search for `\n` and replace with one space, replace all.

Comment: You write: "I know LaTeX doesn't read new lines however". This is not exactly true. In fact, TeX tokenization processor (which has no common with LaTeX) replaces each end of line by a space and replaces empty line by `\par`. And this behavior is only default when appropriate catcodes and `\endlinechar` register have default values.

Comment: Select text to wrap → Idefix menu  →Line break ... → then you can choose characters per line **and**  mark "join lines before to adjust" or some similar   (sorry,  I am watching TexStudio  in Spanish, maybe translation is not exact).

Comment: TeX processes input line by line: When TeX's mouth needs characters, then TeX's eyes read a line of .tex-input and convert the characters of that line to the TeX-engine's internal character-encoding scheme. All spaces (and with some TeX-implementations based on some Web2c-implementations, although deviating from the TeXbook, also horizontal tabs) are removed from the right end of the line. A character is appended whose codepoint-number in the TeX-engine's internal character-encoding-scheme equals the value of the integer-parameter `\endlinechar`. ...

Comment: ...  Then the characters go to TeX's mouth where they get tokenized on demand according to the current catcode-régime whenever TeX's gullet requires tokens from the mouth. Tokens go from TeX's mouth to the gullet where in a regurgitative process expansion of expandable tokens takes place. The tokens resulting from expansion go from the gullet to the stomach.

Comment: Usually the value of `\endlinechar` is 13, denoting the carriage-return-character. Usually the category-code of the carriage-return-character is 5 (end of line). If TeX's mouth encounters a character of category 5 while not gathering the first character of the name of a control sequence token the remaining characters of the line are dropped and in case of the reading-apparatus being in state M a space token, being in state N the token `\par`, being in state S no token at all is produced and appended to the token-stream which goes down the gullet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I was after is below.

Idfix -> hard line break -> set at 0 (smart scoping and join lines).

Now all i needed to do was set a short cut key for this.

configure texstudio -> shortcuts -> idefix -> locate hard line break and set my own short cut key.

Now every time, I have a long text that I want to condense into 1 line, i simply select the entire long text, press my shortcut key and it condenses it into one line.

Thank you everyone!